# ASP.NET core 3.1 :Adding Classes Libraries to the Project_ MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm working on `asp.net-core 3.1` project, I have added 3 Class Library for my project to separate Access Data, Models class and Utility classes I resolved problems of matching folders etc. But when I run my project I get this Error:

```
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrationsModelDiffer.HasDifferences(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IModel)'.


   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext 
   httpContext)
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine 
   stateMachine)
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<TStateMachine>(ref TStateMachine 
   stateMachine)
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext 
   httpContext)
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Do you EF core versions match across your different libraries? Showing the package references from your csproj files would help

Comment: install different version of ef

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me, the answer was to make sure all of my EF packages were pointing at the same 3.1.X version.  I had inadvertently targeted a 5.0.0 EF package that included the missing method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.imigrationsmodeldiffer.hasdifferences?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks.I Only update all entityframework library from 3 to 5 then it is work.

Answer (score 7):

A straight forward fix for me in Dotnet core 3.1 is to comment out

```
app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
```

in the startup.cs file Configure Method

Comment: is this really a fix?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution can Help for ERROR:

**MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.IMigrationsModelDiffer.HasDifferenc**

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22687